# how to give a json with about 1000 fields random values

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a json with about 1000 fields like below

```
{
  "Order": {
    "AdjustmentInvoicePending": "",
    "AllAddressesVerified": "",
    "AllocationRuleID": "",
    "AuthorizationExpirationDate": "",
    "BillToKey": "",
    "CarrierAccountNo": "",
    "ChainType": "",
    "ChargeActualFreightFlag": "",
    "ComplimentaryGiftBoxQty": "",
    "ContactKey": "",
    "CustomerAge": "",
    "CustomerEMailID": "",
    "CustomerFirstName": "",
    "CustomerLastName": "",
    "CustomerPhoneNo": "",
    "CustomerZipCode": "",
    "Division": "",
    "DocumentType": "",
    "DraftOrderFlag": "",
    "EnterpriseCode": "",
    "EntryType": "",
    "FreightTerms": "",
    "HasDeliveryLines": "",
    "HasDerivedChild": "",
    "HasDerivedParent": "",
    "HasProductLines": "",
    "HoldFlag": "",
    "HoldReasonCode": "",
    "InvoiceComplete": "",
    "isHistory": "",
    "MaxOrderStatus": "",
    "MaxOrderStatusDesc": "",
    "MinOrderStatus": "",
    "MinOrderStatusDesc": "",
    "NoOfAuthStrikes": "",
    "NotifyAfterShipmentFlag": "",
    "OrderClosed": "",
    "OrderDate": "",
    "OrderHeaderKey": "",
    "OrderNo": "",
    "OrderType": "",
    "OriginalTax": "",
    "OriginalTotalAmount": "",
    "OtherCharges": "",
    "PaymentRuleId": "",
    "PaymentStatus": "",
    "PendingTransferIn": "",
    "PriorityNumber": "",
    "ReqCancelDate": "",
    "ReturnByGiftRecipient": "",
    "SaleVoided": "",
    "ScacAndService": "",
    "ScacAndServiceKey": "",
    "SellerOrganizationCode": "",
    "ShipToKey": "",
    "SourcingClassification": "",
    "Status": "",
    "Tax": "",
    "TotalAdjustmentAmount": "",
    "AdditionalAddresses": {
      "AdditionalAddress": [
        {
          "AddressType": "",
          "EntityKey": "",
          "PersonInfoKey": "",
          "PersonInfo": {
            "AddressID": "",
            "AddressLine1": "",
            "AddressLine2": "",
            "AddressLine3": "",
            "AddressLine4": "",
            "AddressLine5": "",
            "AddressLine6": "",
            "AddressType": "",
            "AlternateEmailID": "",
            "Beeper": "",
            "City": "",
            "Company": "",
            "Country": "",
            "DayFaxNo": "",
            "DayPhone": "",
            "Department": "",
            "EMailID": "",
            "EveningFaxNo": "",
            "EveningPhone": "",
            "FirstName": "",
            "IsAddressVerified": "",
            "IsCommercialAddress": "",
            "JobTitle": "",
            "LastName": "",
            "Latitude": "",
            "Longitude": "",
            "MiddleName": "",
            "MobilePhone": "",
            "OtherPhone": "",
            "PersonID": "",
            "PersonInfoKey": "",
            "State": "",
            "Suffix": "",
            "TaxGeoCode": "",
            "Title": "",
            "ZipCode": ""
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

I want an output like "AdjustmentInvoicePending": "WQEMQAMCDQ", With all null spots replace with random unique values which changes each time i run the code

I tried using python and coverted json and assigned it to variable but am stuck from their i am new to programming and first time posting on slack please go easy on me if you are not able to understand and please forgive any typo

Answer (score 0):

I recommend just using nested loops to iterate through and add random values.  A snippet is below.  You'll need to change it to work precisely for your problem.  With that said, you can't *guarantee* randomness and uniqueness.  For *most* uses, you can get by with just using a pseudorandom generator, but there is always the chance for collisions when dealing with randomness.

Also, this will fail with the list embedded in the dictionary, so you'll need to add some extra control-flow logic to deal with that circumstance, but this should help with getting you started.

```
import string
import random
N = 10  # length of the string
for i in json_var.keys():  # json_var is your json
    for j in i.keys():
        json_var[i][j].join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase, k=N))
```